# Mean of time component only of pandas datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe, with a column of datetimes.  I need to find the average time of this column, regardless of the date.  For example, if I had

```
dte
----
2018-02-20 20:30:00
2018-09-03 20:30:00
2017-05-18 21:00:00
2014-11-26 21:00:00
```

I would expect a result of

```
20:45:00
```

I've tried simply taking the time component of the datatime objects and averaging them, a la

```
df['tm'].dt.time.mean()
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Comment: @Kevin Regardless of date. Maybe some phenomena he observed follow a diurnal pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to deduct the normalized `datetime` and then calculate mean of `timedelta` series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2018-02-20 20:30:00', '2018-09-03 20:30:00',
                                '2017-05-18 21:00:00', '2014-11-26 21:00:00']})

# convert to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

# take difference to normalized datetime
df['time'] = df['datetime'] - df['datetime'].dt.normalize()

# calculate mean and format
res = str(df['time'].mean())[-8:]

print(res)

'20:45:00'
```